# Interrupt signals awake Python process from sleeping and continue where it left off?

Tags: python, multithreading, operating-system, signals, interrupt

The following code will print out the current time every 5 seconds, and it handles keyboard interrupt signals with `int_handler`.

```
from signal import *
import time
from datetime import datetime


def int_handler(*args):
    print 'interrupted'

signal(SIGINT, int_handler)

while True:
    print datetime.now()
    time.sleep(5)
```

However, every time I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> it will print out the current time immediately, and continue running.

```
2016-06-28 18:17:19.441574
2016-06-28 18:17:24.446659
2016-06-28 18:17:29.451759
2016-06-28 18:17:34.452328
^Cinterrupted
2016-06-28 18:17:37.244227
^Cinterrupted
2016-06-28 18:17:37.692217
^Cinterrupted
2016-06-28 18:17:38.236343
^Cinterrupted
2016-06-28 18:17:38.572194
2016-06-28 18:17:43.577122
2016-06-28 18:17:48.577242
```

It seems that the interruption awakes the process from sleeping, the handler gets executed, and somehow it gets back to the while loop again.

Can someone explain it to me why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `sleep()`:

> The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep

So what you describe is exactly what is happening: after handling the signal in your signal handler execution continues after the sleep, which is the last expression in your while-loop.

Hence in order to really sleep approximately 5 seconds ignoring interruptions you'd have to store the time before sleep and check on waking up that enough has passed, or sleep some more.